# Naudio unvalid operation exception unhandeled

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, naudio, audio

I am using Naudio in WPF for the first time.It keeps giving an exception "InvalidOperationException was unhandled".Buffer Bull.I don't know how to handle it. So far there is no error that is being shown by the debugger.
The Lines that are throwing the exception
waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded); and 
sourceStream.StartRecording();

```
public partial class voiceNote : Window    
{
    public voiceNote()

       {
        InitializeComponent();

       }

    public NAudio.Wave.WaveIn waveSource = null;
    public NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveFile = null;

    private void resources_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities> sources = new List<NAudio.Wave.WaveInCapabilities>();
        for (int i = 0; i < NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
        {
            sources.Add(NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i));
        }
        //to make sure refreshed
        devicesList.Items.Clear();
        foreach (var source in sources)
        {
            //ListViewItem item;
            devicesList.Items.Add(source.ProductName);
            //= new ListViewItem(source.ProductName.ToString);
            //item.SubItem.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(item, source.Channels, ToString()));
            //sourceList.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }

    //to get input....Sound Source
    NAudio.Wave.WaveIn sourceStream = null;

    //To sync the source of input and input audio
    NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut waveOut = null;

    // To write wve file
    NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter waveWriter = null;

    private void startRecording_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // if (devicesList.SelectedItem.Count = 0) return;
        int devicenumber = devicesList.SelectedIndex;
       // int devicenumber = devicesList.SelectedItems[0].index;
        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = devicenumber;
        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(devicenumber).Channels);
        NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);

        //*****************************
        //waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        //waveOut.Init(waveIn);
        //sourceStream.StartRecording();
        //waveOut.Play();
        sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(sourceStream_DataAvailable);
     //   waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(sav.FileName, sourceStream.WaveFormat);
        sourceStream.StartRecording();

    }

    private void sourceStream_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {

    //    //data is byte array, buffer, count
    //    waveWriter.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    //     waveWriter.Flush(); //to write on disk.... so data is not held up on the ram
   }

    private void stopandsave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (waveOut != null)
        {
            waveOut.Stop();
            waveOut.Dispose();
            waveOut = null;

        }
        //Stop Recording
        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.StartRecording();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }
        if (waveWriter != null)
        {
            waveWriter.Dispose();
            waveWriter = null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: No one is going to be able to help you if you don't indicate the line of code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: waveFile.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);  
sourceStream.StartRecording();
are the ones throwing exceptions